# How to center linearlayout with 6 buttons on the center on portrait and landscape orientation?

Tags: android

What I want to achieve: Center layout with both orientation.

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fffffce0">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fffffce0"
    android:weightSum="1">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/a_d"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:onClick="goToAd"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/e_h"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/i_l"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_square"
            android:text="@string/q_t"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PROBLEM:
Everything was ok, until the moment  i was tested my app on tablet with bigger screen. When orientation is landscape, everyting is ok, but when i rotate screen, then it looks like that:
http://zapodaj.net/b2780f7e637ab.png.html

I tried to set my gravity i Llayout to center, but it didnt work.

Comment: try removing `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` from every `View` inside your `LinearLayout`

Comment: Can you post the whole XML? It looks incomplete.

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar and @ Faruk Yazıcı , my bad i pasted wrong activity, now is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ! Like This. Try This..

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fffffce0" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fffffce0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="goToAd"
            android:text="a_d"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="e_h"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="i_l"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="q_t"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: Well. These are the effects on My side. You want the same?

Comment: know its problem on my mobile, this 2 button on the top are cutted  when i change orientation to landscape

Comment: Samsung galaxy core 2, its scrolling down, but this top buttons are cutted http://zapodaj.net/fd9d739d1d574.jpg.html

Comment: i checked it with others layouts and for every time this same problem, cutted upper piece

Answer (score 1):

because of the different screen resolutions, try not to use those hard-coded digits like `android:layout_height="70dp"` for example. You can set the layout parameters programmatically for each element of your layout respectively to the actual screen resolution and in this case it will work on every screen size and oriantation. Try with something like this:

```
//declare two global variables that will have the width and height values
private int width;
private int height;

//define a method that will set the values to the both variables
private static void getScreenResolution(Context context){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    width = metrics.widthPixels;
    height = metrics.heightPixels;
}
```

In your `onCreate()` method first call the method above to get the values and then set the layout params (just a simple example):

```
getScreenResolution(this); //if you are in a fragment, type getActivity() instead of this
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                             LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
layoutParams.setMargins(width/10, height/15, 0 ,0);   //left, top, right, bottom
yourLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Hopefully this helps you to create more general designs in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fffffce0" >

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/layout" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fffffce0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:onClick="goToAd"
            android:text="a_d"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="e_h"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
             android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="i_l"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:background="#fffffce0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="m_p"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="q_t"
            android:textColor="#ffff"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: know its problem on my mobile, this 2 button on the top are cutted  when i change orientation to landscape

Comment: create the dimens file and use the button height value from the dimens file. or set the buttons height values small such as 50dp.   thanks @Ortoh