# In linearLayout i have got cutted upper part oh application

Tags: android

What i want to achieve: for both orientation good looking buttons in LinearLayout

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fffffce0">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fffffce0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/bMnemo"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/bMnemo"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="mnemotechniki"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bZnasz"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:text="@string/bZnasz"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="znasz"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:text="@string/b1000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="metoda1000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bMoje"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_unactive"
        android:text="@string/bMoje"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="moje"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/b_active_pressed"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/b_active"
        android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/b_active" />
</selector>
```

Problem: When i rotate my screen on phone (to landscape, start screen) upper part of app is cutted, like in the photo:
http://zapodaj.net/15ab989809a33.jpg.html

(a (in the picture) - cutted part)

Comment: but scroll doesnt start when i want, i have got 4 buttons, and 1st one is cutted. I just cant see 1st button

Comment: you go with relative layout, like android:layout_below=Your button will work

Comment: @Mano but then my layout will not be centerd, and on my tablet there will be big white space, like here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31070516/how-to-center-linearlayout-with-6-buttons-on-the-center-on-portrait-and-landscap/31070845#comment50161286_31070845

Comment: inside that linear layout use relative layout for each button. make id for relative layout then fix each button android:layout_below="id/Relativelaout1" like this i used

Comment: Can you post the xml (if it's xml) for `@drawable/custon_button_active`

Answer (score 0):

use weight sum and remove margin top from your button layout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#fffffce0">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fffffce0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
android:weightSum="4"
    >
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:id="@+id/bMnemo"

        android:text="@string/bMnemo"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="mnemotechniki"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bZnasz"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:text="@string/bZnasz"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="znasz"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1000"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:background="@drawable/custon_button_active"
        android:text="@string/b1000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="metoda1000"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/bMoje" 
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_unactive"
        android:text="@string/bMoje"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:onClick="moje"
        android:layout_weight="1"``
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer, or some sample XML as to what parameters you mean?